# Google Cloud Run + Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to link a CNAME record to a cloud run domain with the proxy functionality enabled on Cloudflare?
I'm getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. When I disable the proxy functionality it's working but I want to make use of the more advanced proxy features. Is there some way to bypass this easily?

Comment: Yes, you can use CNAME and A resource records at Cloudflare. Edit your question with specific details on what you have configured. Which proxy? How are you testing this when you receive the `ERR_SSL_VERION_...` error?

Comment: Seems to work if I use single level subdomains. The only issue remaining is verifying CNAME records on GCP when they are in Cloudflare proxied mode.

When I disable the CNAME proxied functionality my DNS records get instantly validated on GCP. Don't know if my certificates will renew when I turn the proxied functionality on within Cloudflare?

Comment: @Glenn are you using Cloudflare Host header rewrite feature to rewrite requests with .run.app header? I believe if requests come with header `Host: customdomain.com`, Cloud Run will not recognize and serve that –even if you're creating CNAME records to your `*.a.run.app` domains. – What you're getting with the SSL error here is actually more like a 404 "I don't have a cert for that domain" error.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

1. Select a Cloud Run zone where managed domains are available. Domain mapping is available in the following regions:

   - asia-east1
   - asia-northeast1
   - asia-southeast1
   - europe-north1
   - europe-west1
   - europe-west4
   - us-central1
   - us-east1
   - us-east4
   - us-west1
2. Deploy your Cloud Run service.
3. Add your custom domain linked to your cloud run service. [More info here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#run)
4. Disable the Proxy option in Cloudflare initially, or Google will encounter issues when creating the certificate.
5. Enable full SSL/TLS encryption to avoid excessive redirects and ensure the domain functions correctly. You can do this in Cloudflare under "SSL/TLS" -> "Overview" -> "Full."
6. Enable the Proxy option in Cloudflare.

After completing these steps, your setup should work without experiencing an infinite redirect loop or ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error.